How to Serve media files on render.com for Django app deployed?
Below is following render.com documentation for serving static and media when deploying Django webapp. Everything works, except when you upload a profile picture. Below, setting.py, build.sh and render.yaml code. It was deployed via blueprint instance with PostgreSQL. Also useing PGAdmin 4 GUI
If you spot an issue, great. If not I have spent A week on my Linux/Ubuntu machine on my Windows OP laptop trying to get Nginx to serve the media files.
https://djangocareershifterswebsite.onrender.com (with sqlite 3 db)
https://careershiftforum.onrender.com (with postgresql db)

setting.py

import os
import dj_database_url
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key

# Generate or retrieve SECRET_KEY from environment variables
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', default=get_random_secret_key())

# Define BASE_DIR to point to the root directory of your Django project
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", "False").lower() == "true"

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['careershiftforum.onrender.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'base.apps.BaseConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.User'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'careershiftforum.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'careershiftforum.wsgi.application'

# Use dj_database_url to parse the DATABASE_URL environment variable
DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default=DATABASE_URL)
}


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Whitenoise configuration for serving static files in production
if not DEBUG:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# CORS settings (allow all origins for testing purposes)
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True


render.yaml file

databases:
  - name: postgres
    plan: free
    databaseName: ####
    user: ####

services:
  - type: web
    plan: free
    name: careershiftforum
    runtime: python
    buildCommand: "./build.sh"
    startCommand: "python -m gunicorn careershiftforum.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"
    envVars:
      - key: DATABASE_URL
        fromDatabase:
          name: postgres
          property: connectionString
      - key: SECRET_KEY
        generateValue: true
      - key: WEB_CONCURRENCY
        value: 4



build.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Exit on error
set -o errexit

# Modify this line as needed for your package manager (pip, poetry, etc.)
pip install -r requirements.txt

# Convert static asset files
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# Apply any outstanding database migrations
python manage.py migrate


Serving files with nginx: Main issue retrieving SSL scertificates from render.com/access denied
Nginx Configuration:
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/careershiftforum
Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name careershiftforum.onrender.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

Serve HTTPS requests
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name careershiftforum.onrender.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/careershiftforum.onrender.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/careershiftforum.onrender.com.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/careershiftforum/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/careershiftforum/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        internal;
    }
}

Enable the Site Configuration:
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/careershiftforum /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Create Directories and Set Permissions:
Ensure the directories for your website, static, and media files exist and set the correct permissions.
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/careershiftforum/static
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/careershiftforum/media
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/careershiftforum
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/careershiftforum

Install SSL Certificate:
sudo mkdir -p /etc/nginx/ssl
sudo cp /path/to/your/certificate.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/careershiftforum.onrender.com.crt
sudo cp /path/to/your/private.key /etc/nginx/ssl/careershiftforum.onrender.com.key


Gunicorn Socket Configuration:
Ensure Gunicorn is set up to serve your Django application and create a socket file.
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

ini
Copy code
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/django/project
ExecStart=/path/to/your/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          yourproject.wsgi:application

WantedBy=multi-user.target

Reload the systemd daemon and start the Gunicorn service:

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn

Test Nginx Configuration:
Test the configuration to ensure there are no syntax errors.
sudo nginx -t

Res
tart Nginx:
Restart Nginx to apply the changes.
Open your browser and navigate to https://careershiftforum.onrender.com/media/your-uploaded-file.jpg
404 error, and nginx failed to get access to render.com! Please advise.
I tried django documentation, render.com documentation and nginx.
Media not being saved or even loaded when profile pic is updated.
Nginx configuraion access issue.`
